# Query no puede utilizarse como parametro de tipo TQuery en el método genérico IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>

Tags: c#, asp.net, cqrs

Tengo implementado un proyecto con patrón de diseño CQRS, a la hora de llamar el QueryHandler de la siguiente manera:

```
private readonly IQueryHandler<VendedorTodosQuery, List<VendedorView>> VendedorTodosQueryHandler;
```

Me arroja el siguiente **error**:

```
'VendedorTodosQuery' no puede utilizarse como parámetro de tipo 'TQuery'
 en el tipo o método genérico 'IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>'.                        
 No hay conversión de referencia implícita de 'PosApp.Service.Queries.VendedorTodosQuery' 
 a 'PosApp.Service.IQuery<System.Collections.Generic.List<PosApp.Views.VendedorView>>'
```

Tengo definidas las siguientes interfaces:

**IQueryHandler**

```
public interface IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>
    where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>
{
    Task<TResult> Handle(TQuery query);
}
```

**IQuery**

```
public interface IQuery<TResult>
{
}
```

**VendedorTodosQuery**

```
public class VendedorTodosQuery : IQuery<List<VendedorView>>
{
}
```

**VendedorTodosQueryHandler**

```
public class VendedorTodosQueryHandler : IQueryHandler<VendedorTodosQuery, List<VendedorView>>
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

        public VendedorTodosQueryHandler(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

        public Task<List<VendedorView>> Handle(VendedorTodosQuery query)
        {
            return unitOfWork.VendedorRepository.All()
                            .Select(c => new VendedorView()
                            {
                                Nombre = c.Nombre
                            }).ToListAsync();
        }
    }
```

También tengo mapeado este query handler en un ServiceCollectionExtension, que a su vez en el StartUp.

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddQueryHandlers(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<IQueryHandler<VendedorTodosQuery, List<VendedorView>>, VendedorTodosQueryHandler>();
        return services;
    }
}
```

En caso de necesitar otra parte del código no duden en pedirla. Saludos y gracias